# Synchronized deleting from two tables by expired date

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, foreign-keys, derby

I have three tables in my database:

First one of `COMPANY` that includes `id`, `name` and `email`.
Second - `COUPON` that includes id`,` `title`, `dates`, `price` etc...
Third - join table `COMPANY_COUPON` that includes `id` of the companies and `id` of the coupons which they own.

In java, I have a method that deletes expired coupons using:

```
DELETE FROM COUPON WHERE END_DATE < CURRENT_DATE
```

But after deleting expired coupons, I still have their `id` in `COMPANY_ COUPON` join table, how can I solve this?

```
@Override
public void removeExpiredCoupons() throws CouponSystemException {

    String delete = "DELETE FROM COUPON WHERE END_DATE < CURRENT_DATE";

    Connection connection = pool.getConnection();

    try (PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(delete)) {
        pstmt.executeUpdate();

        // This line can be removed
        System.out.println("All expired coupos are removed.");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new CouponSystemException("Removing expired coupons is failed. ", e);
    } finally {
        pool.returnConnection(connection);
    }
}
```

Comment: Delete the row(s) from the second table in your same method? YOu could probably also write a trigger to delete from the second table.

Comment: is you question about automating the process of deleting the referring values when the referred row is deleted?

Comment: Setting Company as owner of the Company-Coupon table would automatically delete it, however for Coupon you would need additional line in your method something like: **company.coupons.remove(coupon)** @Andrew

Comment: The first thing you are deleting data only form COUPON table. You need to delete an association from COMPANY_COUPON too. Also, it looks like you are not using any constraints on the tables. I would suggest you should add some constraints to the association table and delete data from the association table first then from COUPON table.

Comment: Or alter your sql table by setting it on cascade delete!

Comment: You should define your tables with foreign key constraints that are on delete cascade.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel In joined table, foreign key constraints are assumed from tables joined.

Comment: @MS90 And what is `COMPANY_COUPON`? A join-table, in other words, that is the table that should have foreign key constraints to `COUPON` and `COMPANY` (and definitely not the other way around that you seem to imply). This will allow if they are `on delete cascade` to automatically delete the record if the referenced record from `COUPON` gets deleted.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Exactly! Therefore no need for defining it in your tables whatsoever, foreign key constraints are already there, referential action **on delete cascade** could be applied however.

Comment: @MS90 the fact the OP was able to delete `COUPON` suggests that there currently is no constraint, otherwise the delete would have been rejected or the record would have been deleted.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel He is able to delete **COUPON** and that's not an issue from his question, what he asked about is deleting a corresponding entry from **COMPANY-COUPON** once entry from **COUPON** table is deleted and that can be achieved by referential action **on delete cascade** on COMPANY-COUPON !

Comment: @MS90 You say _"foreign key constraints are already there"_. And I pointed out that that is unlikely, because if that were the case then either the delete would have been forbidden (because the default of a constraint is `on delete restrict`), or he would have never had to ask the question (because then the record in `COMPANY_COUPON` would have been automatically deleted by the constraint). In other words, he will need to add a foreign key constraint with `on delete cascade` and not just add a referential action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you currently have no foreign key constraints defined from `COMPANY_COUPON` to `COUPON` (nor to `COMPANY`). That is undesirable, because it results exactly in the problem you describe.

If you want records in `COMPANY_COUPON` to get automatically deleted if the record is deleted, you need to define a foreign key constraint from `COMPANY_COUPON` to `COUPON` and make it `on delete cascade`.

For example you can add one with

```
alter table COMPANY_COUPON 
  add constraint fk_company_coupon_coupon 
    foreign key (COUPON_ID) references COUPON (ID) on delete cascade
```

You should do something similar to `COMPANY`.

Comment: Does Derby support foreign key constraints?

Comment: Foreign key constraints are already included! Alter table only for referential action.

Comment: @MS90 Foreign key constraints are not automatically added, you need to explicitly define them, and I don't think the OP did that.

Comment: @nicomp Yes it does. For example see [CONSTRAINT clause](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/ref/rrefsqlj13590.html) in the [Derby Reference Manual](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/ref/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. you COULD:

delete the records in the company_coupon table before deleting the records in the coupon table:

first get a list of the expired id's by retrieving result set of expired id's:

```
select id from coupon where END_DATE < CURRENT_DATE
```

then loop through the result set to delete records of each id:

```
delete from company_coupon where id = idFromLoop
```

lastly delete the records from the coupon table:

```
delete from coupon where END_DATE < CURRENT_DATE
```

2. you SHOULD:

google "foreign key on delete cascade" to see how to use a foreign key to delete associated records across tables.

Comment: Although this works, databases have built-in features that do this for you: no need to do it manually.

Comment: I will try it, seems to me what i am looking at

Comment: So, that works only if i have only one expired coupon... but still thanks